# Partial derivative using Leibnitz Rule

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Hy guys,

I'm having troubles on this PDE problem:

Fixed $s \in \mathbb{R}$, consider
$$w(x,t;s)=\frac{1}{2c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}h(z,s)dz.$$

I already proved that $w$ satisfies
\begin{eqnarray}\label{eqondainfinitanaohomog3}
 \displaystyle{
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
  w_{tt}-  c^2 w_{xx}=0, \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}, \ t>0,\\
  w(x,0;s) =  0, \ w_t(x,0;s)=h(x,s), x \in \mathbb{R}.
  \end{array}\right.}
 \end{eqnarray}

Now, I defined
$$u(x,t)=\int_0^t w(x,t-s;s)ds$$
And I don't know how to calculete $\partial u_{tt}$. I know that,
$$\partial_t u(x,t)= 1. w(x,t-t;t)+ \int_0^t \partial_t w(x,t-s;s)ds= w(x,0;t)+ \int_0^t \partial_t w(x,t-s;s)ds.$$

Now I need to prove that $$ \partial_{tt} u(x,t) = h(x,t)+c^2 \partial_{xx} u_1(x,t)$$ (if I prove it, I will have a solution of an inhomgeneous problem in wich I'm working)

I tried to derivate using Leibnitz Rule, but I'm finding an extra term in the sum:
$$\partial_{tt} u_1(x,t) = \partial_t w(x,0;t)+ 1 \partial_t w(x,0;t)+ \int_0^t \partial_{tt}w(x,t-s;s)ds=2h(x,t)+c^2 \partial_{xx} u_1(x,t). $$

Thanks for any help with this derivative!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using another strategy. My goal was solving

\begin{eqnarray}
 \displaystyle{
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
  u_{tt}-  c^2 u_{xx}=h(x,t), \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0,\\
  u(x,0) =  f(x), \ u_t(x,0)=g(x), x \in \mathbb{R}.
  \end{array}\right.}
 \end{eqnarray}
in which $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$, $g \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $h(x,t)$ is an arbitrary function.

I divided the problem into two auxiliary problems. The first of them has a solution guaranteed by d'Alembert's formula.

The second, I was able to solve using the Green Theorem in the region corresponding to the dependency interval of a given point.

I got the solution
$$u(x,t)= \frac{1}{2}(f(x+ct)+f(x-ct))+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(s)ds
+\frac{1}{2c} \int_0^t \int_{x-c(t-s)}^{x+c(t-s)} h(z,s)dzds.$$

Thanks a lot!